Включать экран при подключении монитора или мыши
На компьютере с Windows 11 настроено отключение экрана через 5 минут неактивности, при этом перехода в спящий режим, гибернации и чего-то ещё подобного нет.

Как сделать, чтобы при подключении к компьютеру клавиатуры, мыши или монитора (или хотя бы чего-то одного из этого) экран включался?
Подключение и отключение происходят через отдельные kvm switch'и для usb и hdmi, но в 90+% случаев переключаются оба свича с интервалом в 1 секунду.
